# How to create ObservableCollection with custom class in XAML (UWP)

Tags: xaml, uwp, observablecollection

I would like to generate ObservableCollection for ComboBox ItemsSource in XAML as like below. But it throws exception, please help me.

```
 xmlns:coll="using:System.Collections.ObjectModel"

..

<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Text">
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <coll:ObservableCollection x:TypeArguments="local:EmployeeModel">
                <local:EmployeeModel Text="Male" Value="M"/>
                <local:EmployeeModel Text="Female" Value="F"/>
            </coll:ObservableCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>


 public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public string Text
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please generate `ObservableCollection` in Code-behind.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel> EmployeeCollection = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    EmployeeCollection.Add(new EmployeeModel{Text="Male",Value="M"});
    EmployeeCollection.Add(new EmployeeModel{Text="Female",Value="F"});
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource={x:Bind EmployeeCollection}
          ...
          />
```

Best regards.

Comment: I know the way of code behind generation. I need XAML creation is possible or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ObservableCollection type is not directly supported in XAML. Can you provide the reason for doing this, maybe there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define your items in XAML, you don't need an `ObservableCollection<T>` at all:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Text">
    <local:EmployeeModel Text="Male" Value="M"/>
    <local:EmployeeModel Text="Female" Value="F"/>
</ComboBox>
```

The main reason of using an `ObservableCollection<T>` is when you bind to a view model that may add or remove items from the collection dynamically. If you set up things in XAML, you should add your items to the `Items` property rather than creating another collection.

Comment: Actually the purpose for my custom control ItemsSource property. So that I have asked solution for ComboBox ItemsSource data generation in ObservableCollection.

Comment: I want to the possibility is available or not

Comment: Apparently, you can't create an `ObservableCollection` using `x:TypeArguments` in XAML. You should be able to create a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<EmployeeModel >` and set the `ItemsSource` to an instance of this in XAML.

Comment: @MuneeshKumar: Does this answer your question?